# [MySQL]: Is there a more 'efficient' way to link these tables?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have three tables -

```
Transaction:
ID    TimeStamp

Discount:
Code   Amount

Transaction_Discount:
ID      Code
```

It's almost as basic as you can get.

Is there a more 'efficient' way to link these tables together?

Comment: Is it ia one-one or one-many relationship?

Comment: honestly not quite sure EXACTLY what that is... But I believe it is many-to-many

Comment: Can there be more than one `TRANSACTION_DISCOUNT` record associated to a single `TRANSACTION` record?  If yes - that's a one-to-many relationship.  If no, that's a one-to-one relationship and there's no benefit to having one-to-one relationships because it's the same as having the `CODE` column in the `TRANSACTIONS` table.

Comment: A Transaction can have only one Discount applied, but a Discount can be applied to more than one Transaction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are modelling *a transaction can have 0 or more discounts and a discount can be applied to 0 or more transactions* then this 3 table approach is the standard way to go.

The only change I would make would be to give discount a numeric primary key in addition to the code field and use this as the foreign key in Transaction_Discount.

Answer (score 1):

If it is one to one, then just add a discount code field to your transaction table.

If it is one to many, then add a transaction id to your discount table.

If it is many to many, then the three table solution you have is the only route to go.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, this relationship is a one to many where *one discount can be applied to many transactions*.

Therefore, you should model your tables as follows:

```
Transaction table:
id, discount_id, timestamp

Discount table:
id, code, amount
```

As you can see there is no need for the 3rd link table.  This would only be needed if the relationship was many-to-many.

You can also see, that as a transaction only has one discount, we store the discount ID in the transaction table as a foreign key.  This way we can have many transactions referencing the same discount if we want but each transaction will only ever reference one discount.